# How to Modify/Add a String to JList through a JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I need help in adding a String to a JList through a JOptionPane here's my code so far:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import java.awt.Dimension; 
import java.awt.Color; 
import javax.swing.JButton; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import javax.swing.JList; 
import javax.swing.BoxLayout; 
import javax.swing.JScrollPane; 
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 

/**
 * Write a description of class Front_Menu here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Front_Menu
{
    //Fields 
    private JFrame frame; 
    private JButton button1; 
    private JList list; 
    private JScrollPane listScroller; 
    private JPanel panel1; 
    private String title;

    /**
     * Construct the GUI
     */

    public void go()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Flashcard Maker"); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

        Dimension frameSize = new Dimension(400, 300);
        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(frameSize);        
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        button1 = new JButton("New Set"); 
        button1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button1);

        String[] titleArray ={"Biology Set", title};
        list = new JList(titleArray); 

        listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, listScroller); 

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Main Method 
     */

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Front_Menu front_menu = new Front_Menu(); 
        front_menu.go(); 
    }

    /**
     * Inner class for the Button Listener 
     */

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        /**
         * Override the actionPerformed Method 
         */

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( 
                                null, 
                                "What is the title of your new set? "
                                );       
        }
    }
}
```

So in this program, I have a JList that I would like to modify by adding another String through a JOptionPane. It compiles however, it won't show up when I click on my button.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: `getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button1);` You need to switch the arguments order, read the doc for the method.

Comment: @user1803551 Perhaps you should do to [`Container#add(String, Component)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add-java.lang.String-java.awt.Component-) - it is recommend not to use this method, but it is still valid

Comment: Have you tried giving the button an action command, just for the sake of trying everything?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Didn't know about that one, though obsolete since 1.1 so I'll keep my initial recommendation :)

Comment: When I click the button a `JOptionPane` pops up, does it not for you? Try to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: @user1803551 To my mind, it should be marked deprecated, but it's not :P

Comment: @user1803551 I guess I should be a bit more clear, it does that like it's supposed to, however when I want another thing to show up on the JList after inputting it on the JOptionPane, it doesn't show up.

Comment: @SeanGui. That's because you've not even tried to add anything to the list

Comment: @SeanGui.You get `title` from the user, but you don't do anything with it. See MadProgrammer's answer.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, I'm trying to learn this individually so not everything explicit gets through to me, I appreciate it!

Comment: @user1803551 Thanks for the code and looking at my question, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

After running your code, your `JOptionPane` popups just fine for me.

To answer you other question, start by making using a `DefaultListModel`, which is mutable (allows you to add new elements)

```
public class Front_Menu {
//Fields 

    //...
    private DefaultListModel model;
    private JList list;
    //...

    /**
     * Construct the GUI
     */
    public void go() {
        //...
        String[] titleArray = {"Biology Set", title};
        model = new DefaultListModel();
        for (String title : titleArray) {
            model.addElement(title);
        }
        list = new JList(model);
```

Then in your `ActionListener`, add the input to the model...

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            null,
            "What is the title of your new set? "
    );
    if (title != null) {
        model.addElement(title);
    }
}
```

Have a look at [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details